# Is there a javascript engine (runtime) that doesn't implement Timers interface

Tags: javascript, settimeout

[The Timers interface](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) defined in HTML specification is a widely adopted interface among many javascript engine, including all browser's javascript engines (SpiderMonkey, V8, Chakra...) and the well known NodeJS (V8), but it is not a feature of **javascript itself**, so I'm wondering if there is any javascript engines that does not provide `setTimeout` and `setInterval` as a method of the `global` object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org/) doesn't provide `setTimeout/setInterval`. It *does* provide a `[system.]sleep` method.